# UnityEvent is returning Object as parameters instead of GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a component attached to a Gameobject that contains an event with a Gameobject as parameter:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ReleasedOnDifferent : UnityEvent<GameObject>
{
}
releasedOnDifferent.Invoke(this.gameObject);
```

the event is linked to a simple function as follow:

```
 public void releasedOnDifferent(GameObject gameObject)
 {
 }
```

[image: from ispector]

but when the event is invoked this happens:

> ArgumentException: Object of type 'UnityEngine.Object' cannot be converted to type 'UnityEngine.GameObject'.

it seems that when `Invoke(this.gameObject)` is called a Object type is passed instead of Gameobject

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

[`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html) can have two types of callbacks:

> - **Static**: Static calls are preconfigured calls, with preconfigured values that are set in the UI
>     . This means that when the callback is invoked, the target function is invoked with the argument that has been entered into the UI.

By UI they here mean the Inspector.

> - **Dynamic**: Dynamic calls are invoked using an argument that is sent from code, and this is bound to the type of UnityEvent that is being invoked. The UI filters the callbacks and only shows the dynamic calls that are valid for the UnityEvent.

You selected the **static** method version and are passing in `None` which basically is a `null` placeholder and probably the reason why it can't be converted to a valid `GameObject`.

You rather need to select the **dynamic** version of the method from the upper section of the pop-up menu in order to get the dynamic parameter!

Comment: thank you! this is solved, changed from static to dynamic and it worked!